# AccountId capture on Tree hierarchy

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am bit new to lighting,i got this code from website, My requirement is that i need to populate the account parent ids, everything getting populated but problem is that , i want to take my code automatically, right now i am passing application id  from application. can anyone help me if i put on account page it has to read that account id and populate the structure.

Component

```
<aura:component  controller="SK_AccountTreeGridCmpController">
<aura:attribute name="ltngcurrentRecId" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="gridColumns" type="list" />
<aura:attribute name="gridData" type="Object" />
<aura:attribute name="gridExpandedRows" type="List" access="PRIVATE" />
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

<lightning:treeGrid columns="{! v.gridColumns }"
    data="{! v.gridData }"
    keyField="name"
    expandedRows="{! v.gridExpandedRows}"
    aura:id="mytree" />
```

Application

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
<c:SK_AccountTreeGridCmp ltngcurrentRecId="0010K00001qo2mrQAA"/>
```

APEx class

```
public class SK_AccountTreeGridCmpController {
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Account> findHierarchyData(string recId){
    List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
    string queryString = 'select id,name,type,industry,parentId from Account ';
    //Section to get all child account details from ultimate parent starts-------------------------
    List<String> currentParent      = new List<String>{};
    Integer level               = 0;
    Boolean endOfStructure      = false;
    //method to find ultimate parent of account
    string topMostparent = GetUltimateParentId(recId );
    system.debug('*******topMostparent:'+topMostparent);
    currentParent.add(topMostparent);
    system.debug('**********topMostparent:'+ currentParent);
    //Loop though all children
    string finalQueryString = '';
    List<Account>  queryOutput = new List<Account> ();
    while ( !endOfStructure ){  
        if( level == 0 ){
            finalQueryString = queryString + ' where id IN : CurrentParent ORDER BY ParentId  Limit 1000';
        } 
        else {
            finalQueryString = queryString + ' where ParentID IN : CurrentParent ORDER BY ParentId Limit 1000';
        }
        system.debug('********finalQueryString:'+finalQueryString);
        if(finalQueryString != null && finalQueryString !=''){
            try{
                if(Limits.getLimitQueries()-Limits.getQueries()>0){
                    queryOutput = database.query(finalQueryString);
                    system.debug('***hierarchy level:'+level);
                }else{
                    system.debug('****endOfStructure is true as SOQL limit reaches:');
                    endOfStructure = true;
                }
            }catch(exception ex){ 
                endOfStructure = true;
            }
        }
        system.debug('**queryOutput size:'+queryOutput);
        if( queryOutput.size() == 0 ){
            endOfStructure = true;
        }
        else{
            currentParent.clear();
            //iterating through query output
            for ( Integer i = 0 ; i < queryOutput.size(); i++ ){
                currentParent.add(queryOutput[i].Id);
                accList.add(queryOutput[i]);
             }
        }
        level++;
    }
    system.debug('**********accList:'+accList);
    return accList;
}

// Find the tom most element in Heirarchy  
// @return objId
public static String GetUltimateParentId( string recId ){
    Boolean top = false;
    while ( !top ) {
        string queryString = 'select id ,name, ParentId from Account where Id =:recId LIMIT 1';
        Account acc = database.query(queryString);
        if ( acc.parentId != null ) {
            recId = acc.parentId;
        }else {
            top = true;
        }
    }
    return recId ;
}
```

}

Controller:

```
({
doInit: function (component, event, helper) { 
    console.log('doInit of component called');
    var columns = [
        {
            type: 'url',
            fieldName: 'AccountURL',
            label: 'Account Name',
            typeAttributes: {
                label: { fieldName: 'accountName' }
            }
        },
        {
            type: 'text',
            fieldName: 'Industry',
            label: 'Industry'
        },
        {
            type: 'type',
            fieldName: 'Type',
            label: 'Type'
        }

    ];
    component.set('v.gridColumns', columns);


    var trecid = component.get('v.ltngcurrentRecId');
    //var tsObjectName= component.get('v.ltngSobjectname');
    //var tparentFieldAPIname= component.get('v.ltngParentFieldAPIName');
    //var tlabelFieldAPIName= component.get('v.ltngLabelFieldAPIName');
    if(trecid){
        helper.callToServer(
            component,
            "c.findHierarchyData",
            function(response) {
                var expandedRows = [];
                var apexResponse = response;
                var roles = {};
                console.log('*******apexResponse:'+JSON.stringify(apexResponse));
                var results = apexResponse;
                roles[undefined] = { Name: "Root", _children: [] };
                apexResponse.forEach(function(v) {
                    expandedRows.push(v.Id);
                    roles[v.Id] = { 
                        accountName: v.Name ,
                        name: v.Id, 
                        Type:v.Type,
                        Industry:v.Industry,
                        AccountURL:'/'+v.Id,
                        _children: [] };
                });
                apexResponse.forEach(function(v) {
                    roles[v.ParentId]._children.push(roles[v.Id]);   
                });                
                component.set("v.gridData", roles[undefined]._children);
                console.log('*******treegrid data:'+JSON.stringify(roles[undefined]._children));

                component.set('v.gridExpandedRows', expandedRows);
            }, 
            {
                recId: component.get('v.ltngcurrentRecId')
            }
        );    
    }




}
```

})

Helper class

```
({
callToServer : function(component, method, callback, params) {
    console.log('Calling helper callToServer function');
    var action = component.get(method);
    if(params){
        action.setParams(params);
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(params));
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            //alert('Processed successfully at server');
            callback.call(this,response.getReturnValue());
        }else if(state === "ERROR"){
            alert('Problem with connection. Please try again.');
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

})

Comment: why are you using aura:application just put the component on account page if you want account id and declare an attribute like <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />  and use "force:hasRecordId" interface it will automatically pick

Comment: OK , SO NEED NOT ASSIGN ANY VALUE FOR THIS  <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" /> PLEASE TELL ME , IF I DECLARE LIKE THIS IS THIS FINE ? , I NEED TO  SHOW TREE STRUCTURE FOR THAT ACCOUNT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are placing it on account page and you need account record id you can declare an attribute recordId and use "force:hasRecordId" interface it will automatically pick like this at the top

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId"  controller="SK_AccountTreeGridCmpController">
```

and an attribute

```
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
```

Comment: Hi user, thanks for the reply , will it populate parent hierarchy of that account ?, i am passing account id in application to show the parent hierarchy of that account.

Comment: @Thelearner it will pass the recordid from account record page where your component will be placed the rest of the logic will be handled automatically if you have written code for that

Comment: i have added that attribute and and interface also and added this component to the record page but its not showing the hierarchy of that account.

Comment: have you replaced "ltngcurrentRecId" with "recordId" at all the places

Comment: excellent its working as expected thanks.

Comment: can you tellme how can i select as best answer of ur reply please dont mind

Comment: there will be a "tick" on left side of the answer you can click that